# How to matches any character on elasticsearch request with Spring-Boot and JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to match any character against two characters "*" and "?" in the parameters of a query using JPA and an elasticsearch database.

Example:

In my database I have a "code" String: "AA33BB", "AA38BB", "CG77FF", "DV11PL"...

I wish to receive the first 100 results with the parameter "AA*" to obtain as an answer => "AA33BB", "AA38BB".

But also receive the first 100 results with the parameter "AA3?BB" or "AA??BB" (? in any place) to obtain as an answer => "AA33BB", "AA38BB".

I'm using Java Spring-Boot 3 with elasticsearch dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

////////////////////////
My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CodeRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Code, Long> {

     Iterable<Code> findFirst100CodeContaining(String code);

}
```

////////////////////
My service:

```
@Service
public classServiceCode {

@Autowired
     private CodeRepository codeRepository;

public Iterable<CodeDTO> searchCodes(CodeDTO CodeDTO) {
         String code = codeDTO.getCode();
         code = code.replace("?", ".");
         code = code.replace("*", "");
         Iterable<Code> codeList = codeRepository.findFirst100ByCodeContaining(code);
         return mapToListOfDTO(codeList);
     }
}
```

The SQL version query: @Query("SELECT c FROM codes c WHERE c.code LIKE:code")

It works for "*" but not for "?".

Do you have an idea of the character to replace or how to do otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer it was enough to pass the parameters in this way:

```
@Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"match\": {\"wildcard\": {\"code\": {\"value\": \"?1\"}}}]}}")
```

It works !

Answer (score 0):

I have change my repository by this code:

```
@Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"match\": {\"wildcard\": {\"code\": {\"value\": \"{code}\"}}}]}}")
Iterable<Code> findByCodeAndQuery(String code);
```

And my Service by this code:

```
@Service
public classServiceCode {

@Autowired
     private CodeRepository codeRepository;

public Iterable<CodeDTO> searchCodes(CodeDTO CodeDTO) {
         String code = codeDTO.getCode();
         code = code.replace("?", "*");
         Iterable<Code> codeList = codeRepository.findByCodeAndQuery(code);
         return mapToListOfDTO(codeList);
     }
}
```

My Model is configurated how this:

```
 @Id
 @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
 private String id;

 @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, name = "code")
 private String code;
```

But that doesn't work either...